# On the picture vs over the picture. "On" vs "over"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-choice

I have an image being displayed somewhere, and on the description below it explains:

> There is a watermark **over** the image

Meaning that I added a watermark image on top of the image, covering it a little.

I feel that it is better to say:

> There is a watermark **on** the image.

Is there any difference? Does none of them mean what I want to express?

Or maybe I should just say 'it's on top of the image' and be happy?

Comment: We also use the phrase **superimposed on**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When describing a watermark in relation to an image, I think *on* or *over* are equally suitable. You could probably also use *in*.

I checked on Google, and found far more hits when searching for `"watermark on the picture"` than for `"watermark over the picture"`. However, I think this is one of those cases where prevalence does not necessarily imply correctness. In other words, just because something is less common, that doesn't mean it's less correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I am just over-thinking things. :P
I hope this question ends up being useful for someone else like me though! :)

Comment: Trace over \ trace on the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Well do u know the meaning of over? 
It means to not touch the persisting think but to cross it. 
Eg. He jumped over the table
Eg. He was very happy to be over the swing. 
While on means to touch the persisting thing(leaving some perceptions) 
Eg. He is on the table
Eg. She is on the large rock. 
That's why i guess it would be :-
There is a watermark on the painting.